# Log4net filter and replace the log message?

Tags: log4net

Can log4net filter and replace matched log message?

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" />
  <param name="RegexToMatch" value="&lt;Code>.*&lt;/Code>" />
</filter>
```

This code can match the ...content...of Code and not to write all message to file.

But, what I want is that save the message, and replace the content of Code with empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of such functionality in bundled filters.

You'll probably have to do the job yourself by subclassing [log4Net.Filter.FilterSkeleton](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.FilterSkeleton.html) or StringMatchFilter.

Then in your XML, you'll only have to call

```
<filter type="Your.Application.TheFilterYouJustWrote">
  <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" />
  <param name="RegexToMatch" value="&lt;Code>.*&lt;/Code>" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Maybe you could post it, as several questions on SA evolve around this type of filters